# Calculating true power of a predominantly inductive load?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, ac, impedance

I'm stuck at this problem, which doesn't seem to be so difficult, but, I guess there is some basic stuff that still confuses me.  So, if we have a load represented with complex impedance \$Z=30+j40 \ \Omega\$ powered with a sinusoidal signal generator of voltage \$U=200 \ V\$, how can we find a true power on that load?
What I did, knowing that true power is: \$P=U\cdot I\cdot \cos \phi\$, where \$\phi\$ is phase difference between voltage and current through the load and equals \$\phi=\cos\big(\arctan\frac{X}{R}\big)\$ \$\big(X\$ - reactance, \$R\$- resistance \$\big)\$, since I don't know the current, I expressed it as: \$I=\frac{U}{Z}\$ and then calculated true power as:
$$P=\frac{U^2}{Z}\cos\bigg(\arctan\frac{X}{R}\bigg)=742 \ W$$
but, I think I'm completely missing some parts regarding complex values of impedance and current.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: In your final equation, arctan should be cos(arctan.

Comment: Then calculating that out correctly should give you the correct answer. You made a calculation error.

Comment: Also, there is another way to do it by which you can solve it without a calculator.

Comment: @CharlesCowie What confuses me is putting an equal sign between \$I\$ and \$\frac{U}{Z}\$ (their effective values). Can I really do that?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: Isn't that equality only true for their complex values, not their effective values?

Comment: The effective value of I = U/Z. You lose the complex value of I, but you don't need it for this problem.

Comment: @CharlesCowie If you have time, it would mean a lot if you could describe an alternate method to solve this without a calculator.

Comment: Your equation should give 480 watts. You must have made a calculation error that is not revealed by looking at what you posted.

Comment: I think you may have incorrectly used Z = 30 in your calcualtions? Try using  Z = 50. 30 + 40J = 50 angle 0.927 rad. It works when you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the text below I will use \$\mathbf{Z}\$, \$\mathbf{U}\$, \$\mathbf{I}\$, \$\mathbf{S}\$ as complex numbers and \$Z\$, \$U\$, \$I\$, \$S\$ as their magnitudes.

Note that
$$Z\cos\left(\arctan\frac{X}{R}\right) = \operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{Z})$$
so you can simplify the expression
$$\frac{U^2}{Z}\cos\left(\arctan\frac{X}{R}\right)
= \frac{U^2}{ZZ}Z\cos\left(\arctan\frac{X}{R}\right)
= \frac{U^2}{Z^2}\operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{Z})$$

In fact it's much easier to avoid \$\cos(\varphi)\$ at all from the beginning, since the magnitude of the current is just
$$I = \frac{U}{Z}$$
and, since the current is in phase with voltage at the active resistance, the active (real) power is just
$$P = I^2 R = \frac{U^2}{Z^2}\operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{Z})$$
which is the same formula as above.

---

Also, there is a concept of complex power, usually denoted by \$\mathbf{S}\$. The complex power is defined as
$$\mathbf{S} \equiv \mathbf{U}\mathbf{I}^*$$
where both \$U\$ and \$I\$ are complex numbers and \$\mathbf{I}^*\$ means the complex conjugate. The equivalent formulas are
$$\mathbf{S} = \frac{U^2}{\mathbf{Z}^*} = I^2 \mathbf{Z}$$
Real power \$P = \operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{S})\$

So the alternative way to solve your problem  is
$$P = \operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{U^2}{\mathbf{Z}^*}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Solution without a calculator:

The impedance 30 + J40 can, by inspection, be represented by a 3-4-5 triangle, so Z = 50. I = U/Z = 200/50 = 4. Power = I squared R. 16 X 30 = 480 watts.